# Java File.exists() returns true even when file doesn't exist

Tags: java, file

```
String filePath = "C:\Users\d654227/Desktop/abdc.url"; // Actually its getting constructed dynamically.  

File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists()){
       LogUtil.logConsole(filePath+" File already exist.");
        file.delete();
}else
{
        LogUtil.logConsole(filePath+" File doesnt exist.");
}
```

> Using Windows 7 n IE 9. 
>   Its is getting executed through an applet.  Same code works in our dev enviroinment and most of the customer places except one customer.

Comment: Did you notice the trailing space in your String?

Comment: @mp911de what does that matter?

Comment: Are you sure the file is being deleted in the first place? By default applets don't have access to the local file system.

Comment: Any reason why you mix backslashes and slashes? Maybe `.exists()` just reports that `C:\Users\d654227` exists and ignores the rest.

Comment: There is no real question here. If you delete your file that will return `false` when you call `file.exist()`.

Comment: And again it is `String` not `Sting`. Your code won't even compile.

Comment: won't compile because of invalid escape sequences. If corrected then the output is as expected.

Comment: Hi All, filePath that is mentioned is jus for example purpose. that will get constructed dynamically without any issues.

Comment: In other words this isn't the real code. So post the real code.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your path with all '/'.
And notice is String not Sting.

Comment: This is not an answer, Should be a comment.

Comment: Could you explain why? I have tried his code with these corrections and work like expected, so I think it is an answer